# Como obtener la cabecera http con AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot, http

Estoy llamando una página de AngularJS con SpringBoot, en el SpringBoot le pongo a la cabecera un token para recoger en AngularJS, pero el problema es que no sé como poder ver la cabecera:

En el SpringBoot he puesto:

```
response.addHeader("headerToken", "valueToken");
return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + url);
```

Y cuando llega al cliente en network puedo ver que efectivamente se envía en la cabecera mi token:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cliente lo tengo parado para poder ver el console.log

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado mirando todas las posibles opciones con $http. pero no sale para ver la cabecera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi intención es poder llegar al valueToken que envío desde el Servidor con AngularJS, gracias.

***Edito para añadir más información:***

Yo no tengo acceso al botón de "enviar" que hará el código de

```
 $http(req).then(
                //success
                function (data, status, headers, config) {
                etc
```

Ese botón, es un botón de netplus que si es OK, llamará a mi servicio de Java.

Una vez el Servidor devuelva la url:

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + url);
```

El código Angular pasará por el routerProvider:

```
angular.module('do')
        .config(['$translateProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($translateProvider, $routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('Del servidor', {
                    title: 'Gracias por ..',
                    templateUrl: 'una ruta'
          }
         etc
```

Y cuando se carga la template llama al controlador, he añadido un trozo de código para comprobar si están los datos en la cabecera pero siguen sin aparecer:

```
angular.module('don').controller('Del servidor', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$cookies', '$routeParams', '$window', '$location', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $cookies, $routeParams, $window, $location) {
    var self = this;
    // Load get data
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', document.location, false);
        req.send(null);
        var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
        console.log(headers);
etc
```

Este es el resultado del headers ->

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Cuando haces una consulta en AngularJS usas el objeto `$http`, por ejemplo

```
$http.get('/unaUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    ...
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    ...
  });
```

Como puedes ver, cuando se obtiene una respuesta uno de los parámetros que puedes recibir es `headers`. Ahí encontrarás lo que buscas.

Comment: El problema es que yo no realizo esa llamada al servidor, la hace netplus a mi servidor y mi servidor finalmente devuelve esa ruta -> return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + url);

Comment: He editado el post quizás te ayude a entender mejor el problema.